# In the NextJS tutorial, what is considered as a single "request"?

Tags: next.js

I've been learning NextJS and on the tutorial, I'd like to confirm what is meant by a single "request"?

https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/request-time

Is a request a refresh of a page or if I were to press the F5 key on Chrome?  Or does it mean when the web app makes a request from client to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request here means a user performs a page request to a web app. It can be: typing address in browser URL bar, refreshing page or client-side navigating. Either way is a request.

In other words, when a user asks browser to fetch some page.